# What's the meaning of the word "turn" in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

The following context is from the book *Hitchhikers Guide To The Galaxy*

> The only vestiges left in Mr. L. Prosser of his mighty ancestry were a pronounced stoutness **about the turn** and a predilection for little fur hats.

What does **about the turn** mean in this context?

I would show some research, but I can’t find anything online.

Comment: If you search in Google Books for the text immediately preceding the problematic element: [***ancestry were a pronounced stoutness about the***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22ancestry+were+a+pronounced+stoutness+about+the%22) and ***look carefully***, you'll see that most if not all other instances of this text correctly reflect the word ***tum*** (BrE  ***= tummy = stomach***).

Comment: I’m closing this question because it's based on a typo or reading error, and now that the error has been pointed out, there will be no useful answer for anyone else coming to the site

Answer (score 5):

I will hazard a guess that you are reading this book on an electronic device, is that correct? [The proper quote](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Hitchhiker_s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_The/j24GMN0OtS8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=the%20only%20vestiges%20left%20in%20Mr.%20L.%20Prosser%20of%20his%20mighty%20ancestry&pg=PT21&printsec=frontcover) is "a pronounced stoutness about the **tum**," that is, "the tummy" (belly, abdomen, midriff, etc).

The file you are reading was most likely generated by an Optical Character Recognition scan of a paper copy of the book, and the software misread the "m" character as "rn." This a common error.

Comment: Known as “keming,” as the amount of space between the r and the n is the kerning.

Answer (score 4):

This is a typo in your copy of The Book. The correct description is available on the linked HitchHikers wiki. It is supposed to say "tum".

[Prosser](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Mr_Prosser#:%7E:text=Prosser%20was%20%22only%20human%22%20and,the%20Vogons%20on%20a%20Thursday.)

> "the only vestiges left of his mighty ancestry were a pronounced stoutness about the tum and a predilection for little fur hats"

Meaning (as you may already know) that Mr Prosser had a large belly.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting a Hitchhikers Guide [fan site](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Mr_Prosser)

> In the first novel, Mr. Prosser was described as "forty, fat, and
> shabby".

And contains a further quote from which your phrase comes

> Mr. Prosser was "only human" and was a direct male-line descendant of
> Genghis Khan, although "the only vestiges left of his mighty ancestry
> were **a pronounced stoutness** about the **tum** [UK colloquialism for stomach] and a predilection for
> little fur hats".

I therefore interpret **stoutness about the turn** as a misprint meaning   he was fat, probably around the waist.